# Can't save PATH or JAVA_HOME variables, Oracle Linux 6

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I am on Oracle Linux 6 and I am trying to add the path:

```
/root/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_33-R28.2.4-4.1.0
```

to the `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` variables. So, I login as root and I try:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/root/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_33-R28.2.4-4.1.0 and JAVA_HOME=/root/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_33-R28.2.4-4.1.0.
```

`PATH` does not even add my jdk path, and `JAVA_HOME` adds it as it should. When I `echo JAVA_HOME` from another terminal or after a reboot `JAVA_HOME` returns to default(empty).

I also edited the `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` with vi and I added the above commands but nothing happened.

Any ideas how could I edit these variables properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
export PATH=$PATH:/root/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_33-R28.2.4-4.1.0
export JAVA_HOME=/root/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_33-R28.2.4-4.1.0
```

to your .bash_profile and reload it with the command

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```